# Fold C++ functions (and only functions) in vim

Tags: vim, vi

Is it possible to use folding to fold C++ functions in vim?

I'd like fold only functions and class methods. I don't want to fold classes, namespaces, "if" and "for" statements, and etc. like standard  "set foldmethod=syntax" does.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Vim's built-in syntax folding for C/C++ folds `{ ... }` blocks, regardless of what syntax element they represent. The only configuration that's built-in is `c_no_comment_fold` and `c_no_if0_fold`. What you want would require a syntax extension. Since C/C++ syntax is pretty flexible, recognizing namespaces vs. classes vs. other stuff may be tricky, unless you accept certain limitations (for example, that namespace definitions are not indented, classes indented once, functions indented twice).

Vim has alternative fold methods built-in (cp. `:help 'foldmethod'`), but I'm not aware of any alternate fold implementation for C/C++, so you may have to write your own.

Another approach would be to accept the additional folding, and just tweak what gets folded by default, e.g. via `:setlocal foldlevel=1`.